# Disable File drag & drop if there isn't a file input

Tags: javascript, file-upload, drag-and-drop, fileapi

I think the solution to this is staring me in the face, but I can't seem to find it.

So, I'm making a site that has a small file upload section. The upload section will have a place to upload an image for different devices and device orientations (i.e. iPhone, iPad, portrait and landscape). I can easily figure out how to implement the drag & drop on the individual device icons, but if the user misses the drop area, the browser will just navigate to that image on their system. How do I disable drag & drop if there isn't a file input type to receive the dragged file?

Comment: listen to drag&drop events on the whole page, reject and prevent default?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This document (documentation for a jQuery file upload plugin) shows how to disable the browser's default action:
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Drop-zone-effects

Quoting the document:

> If you want to allow specific drop zones but disable the default browser action for file drops on the document, add the following JavaScript code:

```
$(document).bind('drop dragover', function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
});
```

> Note that preventing the default action for both the "drop" and "dragover" events is required to disable the default browser drop action.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I don't use jQuery, but this helped me figure it out. I just wasn't "drop" was an event, or what the event would be called.

Comment: thanks for info. why dragover is also required? i was using drop only event and it was not working.

Comment: No idea, sorry. Does "not working" mean that the browser navigated away anyways, or only that the mouse cursor indicated a drop target? The latter makes sense - the browser doesn't know in advance the drop event will be prevented.

Comment: This doesn't work at all for me. I found that solution in the documentation but it just doesn't do anything. I can still drag/drop anywhere on the page and it attempts to upload.

Comment: @BadHorsie you need to return false as stated below

Answer (score 1):

This might not be relevant to the topic, but it is just reverse. If you don't want to drag-drop file in input file up-loader, you can use

```
$('body').on('drop', function (e) {
     return false;
});
```

It worked for me in both IE 11 and chrome. Thanks Francois for your similar guidelines

Comment: it gets difficult if you have multiple drop zones, so you might want to turn it off sometimes

Answer (score 0):

the dropzone must be inside the form without any HTML elements:

```
<form id="frmdropzone" class="dropzone" action="Save" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <div class="dropzone-previews"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: <form id="frmdropzone" class="dropzone" action="Save" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <div class="dropzone-previews"></div>
</form>

Answer (score -1):

To improve on Jan's answer, if you don't want to disable the drag & drop on file input elements:

```
$(document).bind("drop dragover", function(e){
    if(e.target.type != "file"){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: Chrome reports that `e.target.type` is undefined