# Disable Drag and Drop Functionality for jQuery-File-Upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I'm using ajax file uploader on my pages.
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

I'm using one control for image uploading and another for file uploading and both are on the same page.

I've added the validation to check the file type in both of the file uploaders but when I drag and drop resume on my file uploader then it will catch the image uploader event.

I want to disable the functionality of drag and drop for image uploader so it will not trigger when i drag my resume.

Here's my code,

```
$(function () {

        var userId = $("#CandidateProfile_user_id").val();    
        var url = 'index.php?r=fileUpload/uploadResume';
        $('#resumeUpload').fileupload({
            add: function(e, data) {
                var uploadErrors = [];
                var acceptFileTypes = /^document\/(doc|docx)$/i;

                var fileName = data.originalFiles[0].name;
                var fileExtension = fileName.split('.')[1];

                if(fileExtension.toLowerCase() != "doc" && fileExtension.toLowerCase() != "docx") {
                      uploadErrors.push('Not an accepted file type');
                }
//                if(data.originalFiles[0]['type'].length && !acceptFileTypes.test(data.originalFiles[0]['type'])) {
//                    uploadErrors.push('Not an accepted file type');
//                }
                if(data.originalFiles[0]['size'].length && data.originalFiles[0]['size'] > 5000000) {
                    uploadErrors.push('Filesize is too big');
                }
                if(uploadErrors.length > 0) {
                    alert(uploadErrors.join("\n"));
                } else {
                    data.submit();
                }
        },
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        formData: {userId : userId},       
        done: function (e,data) {

            onFileUploaded(data.result.fileName,data.result.filePath);

            //Update the pic
           // $("#userPic").attr('src',data.result.imagePath);

            //set the image name
           // $("#CandidateProfile_image_name").val(data.result.imageName);

            //console.log(data);
        },       
    }).prop('disabled', !$.support.fileInput)
        .parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled');
});
```

Thanks,
Faisal Nasir

Comment: I think the UI of the file selection dialogue is out of control of Javascript.

Comment: I think that is the same

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13082192/disable-file-drag-drop-if-there-isnt-a-file-input

Comment: it will disable all the file upload controls. my problem is to disable one of them since i've two file upload controls.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable drag & drop by setting the `dropZone` option to `null`.

```
$('#resumeUpload').fileupload({
    dropZone: null,
    add: function(e, data) {
```